# Installing Android App on Motorola Droid

Tags: android, installation, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to install an Android app on an older Motorola Droid but running into some problems. The device has 2.2.3 on it and it says that it is up to date. Can it be updated to the latest version of Android or is it too old?

Also, where can I find the .apk file? And where would I put it on the SD card to allow me to install it that way?

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android OS updates are usually rolled out by the phone manufacturer. In this case it would Motorola. Unless Motorola specifically created an update for the Droid in question, you wouldn't be able to update it to the latest Android OS on your own. For instance, the latest version of Android is Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0). I currently own the first gen. HTC Incredible. I'm not able to upgrade to ICS unless HTC offers an upgrade specifically tailored for my model phone.

The Android OS has had several version updates and in it's wake has created an issue known as "fragmentation", which is the problem you're having. Applications are developed with features available in later versions of the Android OS, which earlier versions can not take advantage of. So you run into older phones not being able to run newer applications. Hope this clears this up a bit.

Comment: I changed the target in my program to 10 (2.2.3). This allowed Eclipse to recognize the phone and I was able to install it. Thanks!